# Estimate token probability/logits given a sentence without computing the entire sentence

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have a sentence like:  `"I like sitting in my new chair and _____ about life"`.

And I have a SPECIFIC set of tokens like `["watch", "run", "think", "apple", "light"]`

I would like to calculate the probability of each of those tokens to appear as the next word in that incomplete sentence. Hopefully I should get that the probability of `"think"` is higher that `"apple"` for instance.

I am working with pytorch-transformers (GPT2LMHeadModel specifically), and a possible solution is to evaluate the score of the full sentence with each of the tokens, but when number of tokens to evaluate is on the order of 100 or 1000 then the computation time starts to be too long.

It must be possible to process the sentence only once and somehow use the hidden states to calculate the probabilities of the set of tokens, but I don't know how to do it.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

---

EDIT:

The actual code looks like the one below (estimating the probability for the full sentence every time). For every sentence it takes about 0.1 seconds to run the `score()` method, which turns into hours if I want to evaluate some thousands of words.

```
from pytorch_transformers import GPT2Tokenizer, GPT2LMHeadModel
import pandas as pd

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model.eval()
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2")


def score(sentence):
    tokenize_input = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence)
    tensor_input = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenize_input)])
    loss = model(tensor_input, labels=tensor_input)
    return -loss[0].item()


candidates = ["watch", "run", "think", "apple", "light"]
sent_template = "I like sitting in my new chair and {} about life"
print({candidate: score(sent_template.format(candidate)) for candidate in candidates})
```

Comment: Maybe you can utilize the [past](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quickstart.html#using-the-past) parameter but I'm not sure. Can you share some code of what you are currently doing?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @cronoik. I have read a bit about the past parameter but I cant make it work either. I have edited the question including the code that I am currently using. Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You might want to follow [this](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5586) but I will also post an answer as soon as it clear to me.

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example produced the following output and took around 48.5 seconds with 282 candidates to finish in my environment (I only conducted 3 runs):

```
{'watch': -5.406847953796387
, 'run': -5.533411502838135
, 'think': -4.525279521942139
, 'apple': -6.158637046813965
, 'light': -5.835141658782959}
```

As mentioned in the comments I think you can spare some calculations with the [past](https://huggingface.co/transformers/quickstart.html#using-the-past) parameter and the fast [tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#transformers.GPT2TokenizerFast) as shown in the commented example below:

```py
import torch

from  transformers import GPT2TokenizerFast, GPT2LMHeadModel
from torch.nn import CrossEntropyLoss

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained("gpt2")
model.eval()
tokenizer = GPT2TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("gpt2")

###We calculate the hidden_states and the past of the common left part of the sentence
past = "I like sitting in my new chair and"
past_tokenize_input = tokenizer.tokenize(past)
past_tensor_input = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(past_tokenize_input)])

past_last_hidden_state, past = model.transformer(past_tensor_input)

def score(sentence, past, past_last_hidden_state, past_tensor_input):
    tokenize_input = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence, )
    tensor_input = torch.tensor([tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokenize_input)])

    ###the following code is slightly modified from https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/09a2f40684f77e62d0fd8485fe9d2d610390453f/src/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py#L604
    ###now we calculate the right part of the sentence with the already calculated past
    transformer_outputs = model.transformer(
            tensor_input,
            past=past,
            attention_mask=None,
            token_type_ids=None,
            position_ids=None,
            head_mask=None,
            inputs_embeds=None,
            use_cache=None,
            output_attentions=None,
            output_hidden_states=None,
        )
    ###and concatenate the output of with the hidden_state of the left part of the sentence
    hidden_states = torch.cat((past_last_hidden_state, transformer_outputs[0]), dim=1)
    
    ###the following part is exactly the same as https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/09a2f40684f77e62d0fd8485fe9d2d610390453f/src/transformers/modeling_gpt2.py#L604
    lm_logits = model.lm_head(hidden_states)

    labels_input = torch.cat((past_tensor_input, tensor_input), dim=1)

    # Shift so that tokens < n predict n
    shift_logits = lm_logits[..., :-1, :].contiguous()
    shift_labels = labels_input[..., 1:].contiguous()
    # Flatten the tokens
    loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
    loss = loss_fct(shift_logits.view(-1, shift_logits.size(-1)), shift_labels.view(-1))
    return -loss.item()

candidates = ["watch", "run", "think", "apple", "light"]

sent_template = " {} about life"

print({candidate: score(sent_template.format(candidate), past, past_last_hidden_state, past_tensor_input) for candidate in candidates})
```

Output:

```
{'watch': -5.406846046447754
, 'run': -5.533413887023926
, 'think': -4.525280952453613
, 'apple': -6.158637046813965
, 'light': -5.835141181945801}
```

The runtime here was 40.5 seconds with 282 candidates (3 cycles again). You also see that I lost some precision.

Many thanks to [patrickvonplaten](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9980587/patrick-von-platen) who gave me a good [explanation](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/5586#issuecomment-655416174) about the past implementation.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I will test this out as soon as I am back from vacations.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked correctly. The reduction in time is not tremendous but it did reduce the computation time from 0.1 secs/sentence to 0.08 secs/sentence. Thanks for your help

Comment: @JacoboLansac You can save some more time when you use the [fast tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/gpt2.html#transformers.GPT2TokenizerFast). I have adjusted my answer.

Comment: I use your procedure exactly as you presented it in your solution, with the FastTokenizer and I got the speed mentioned in the previous comment. Perhaps it is because I am not using GPU.

Comment: The fast tokenizers doesn't utilze GPU's as a far as I know. They are written in rust and work with threads. The improvement of 1.5 seconds could also be just a measuring error.

Comment: Actually, the percentage improvement that we both get matches pretty well. We both get around a 20% speed increase. The absolute time may depend on our processors and what other jobs we were running at the moment. 

You got:
48.5sec /282 candidates = .18 secs.
40.5sec /282 candidates = .144 secs.
That is a reduction of 0,036 seconds per candidate.
In precentage = 0,036/0,18 = 20% time reduction

I got first 0.1 secs per candidate and later 0.08. Reduction of 0.02 seconds. In percentage 0.02/0.1 = 20 % time reduction

:)